# Google custom search api in android application

Tags: android, json, google-custom-search

i've been trying to use the Google custom search api for a school work and been running in to some issues when trying to get the json format of the result, i've configured everything on Google developer console and the Google custom search engine control panel, at least so i think. Here is a my code snippet

```
String qstring = "key="+key + "&cx="+ cx +"&q="+searchtext+"&alt=json"+"&start="+"0";
    String query = null;
    try {
        query = URLEncoder.encode(qstring, "UTF-8")
        .replaceAll("\\%28", "(")
        .replaceAll("\\%29", ")") 
        .replaceAll("\\+", "%20") 
        .replaceAll("\\%27", "'") 
        .replaceAll("\\%21", "!") 
        .replaceAll("\\%7E", "~");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?" + query);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpURLConnection conn2 = null;
    try {
        conn2 = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        conn2.setRequestMethod("GET");
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    conn2.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        (conn2.getInputStream())));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(line + "\n");
        }
        br.close();

    return content.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and the error being displayed in the logcat

```
04-22 07:26:36.253: W/System.err(4229): java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key%3DAIzaSyBgvvgYg3mYS66fMM9j0qpaG6wlvUc1KLk%26cx%3D008838294879486691568%3Axy_pvqrl6fa%26q%3Djava.pdf%26alt%3Djson%26start%3D0
04-22 07:26:36.289: W/System.err(4229):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
04-22 07:26:36.321: W/System.err(4229):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
```

I would appreciate a point in the right direction incase i'm doing something wrong. please help!

Comment: File not found... quite self-explained. Your URL should be: https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyBgvvgYg3mYS66fMM9j0qpaG6wlvUc1KLk&cx=008838294879486691568:xy_pvqrl6fa&q=java.pdf&alt=json&start=0, and read the server JSON response

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help your situation or not but I had a lot of trouble with my search string until I figured out how to encode it properly. I noticed that you're 
doing a lot of manual insertions of codes (e.g., %20) and it may be more reliable to let the object methods do the work. I'm not working in Java but here's how I did it
in C#. I encoded the APIKey, CSKey, and the query separately and added all three to the base google search string. Then I added "&alt=json" to the very end.The string 
variable 'result' holds the returned string.

```
string myQuery = "Action Motivation, Inc.";
string final = string.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={0}&cx={1}&q={2}",
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(APIKey),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(CXKey),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(myQuery));
final += "&alt=json";
WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create(final);
HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
Stream myStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
string result = myReader.ReadToEnd();
```